# Display $http.result body in html (using ExpressJS & angular)

Tags: express

I am a newbie to expressjs.

Need to display the jsnArry in html. Able to see the chunk/jsnArry json inside res.on('data') or res.on('end') but dont know how to pass it to index.html.

Tried res.render/ res.send(jsnArry) but nothing works. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
app.use('/index', function(req, res){
    var getReq = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      jsnArry += chunk; 
    });

     res.on('end', function (chunk) {
         res.body = jsnArry;   
     });
    });
//  res.sendFile(path.join(_dirname, '/html', 'index.html'));

});
```

Comment: have you tried serving it as a static file and simply sending the result using res.json(data)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i tried it doesn't work.. I fixed by passing the value to another middle-ware by calling next inside the res.on('end') method